# How to add horizontal line beneath some divs?

Tags: html, css

I'm sure this will be very basic, but I'm quite new to coding and I'm still learning. I have the following `div`s:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="panel-panel panel-col-left">
  <div class="inside"><?php print $content['top_left']; ?></div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-panel panel-col-middle">
   <div class="inside"><?php print $content['top_middle']; ?></div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-panel panel-col-right">
   <div class="inside"><?php print $content['top_right']; ?></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Now, I'd like to add a horizontal line underneath the whole section, so I tried adding this CSS code:

```
.wrapper {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.panel-col-left {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

.panel-col-middle {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}

.panel-col-right {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}
```

Apparently, this isn't displayed correctly: the horizontal line is situated at the top.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: underneath the whole section or each content section? Also there is no `.top-wrapper` class in your html

Comment: +1 for the Lorum Ipsum passage that mentioned Aldus PageMaker LOL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you floated the child divs, you need to limit the block formatting context of the floated div's container and add `overflow:auto` to `.wrapper` so it can contain them again:

```
.wrapper {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to clear the floating elements. You can use a clearfix or `overflow:hidden` on the `wrapper`

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tFL95/)